# How to develop membership module in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic membership system set up using MySQL database with 3 tables, user_id, user_name and user_password. my php code bellow is simple as I am new to php and will develop it further as my knowledge progresses. I am trying to create different rolls at the moment, member, admin and global admin. I am a bit lost on how to progress on from what I have so far. any advice or suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please give solutions as soon as fast

Comment: where is the php code?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide do you want to have single role for user or maybe users can have more than one role. Create new table (role_id, role_name) and connect it to user table (directly - column `role_id` if users can have only one role or by another table `users_roles`(role_id, user_id)).

Now you can start thinking about permissions table connecting roles to permissions (eg. `show_page`, `edit_page`, `add_user`, etc.)